# Seaborn: Histogram doesn't start at 0

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I'm trying to plot differents histograms in SeaBorn with this code (I've translated from spanish to english, so everyone can understand it):

```
#We assign diffent colours for the mean, the median, and the mode (red, green, and blue), for the legend of the graphics plotted
ref_mean = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='Mean')
ref_median = mpatches.Patch(color='green', label='Median')
ref_mode = mpatches.Patch(color='blue', label='Mode')
tags=[ref_mean,ref_median,ref_mode]

...

ax = sns.displot(data=districts,
            x="POPULATION_DENSITY",
            multiple="stack",
            height=6,
            aspect=2,
            kind='hist', 
            bins=BINNING_VALUE, 
            stat='density',
            kde=True).set(title='Density Population Histogram')

ax.set(xlabel='Density Population (hab/km´2)', ylabel='Relative quantity of districts')

plt.axvline(x=districts.POPULATION_DENSITY.mean(),
            color='red')
plt.axvline(x=districts.POPULATION_DENSITY.median(),
            color='green')
plt.axvline(x=mode(x=districts.POPULATION_DENSITY,BINNING_VALUE),
            color='blue')

plt.legend(handles=tags)

ax = sns.displot(data=districts,
            x="UBN_PERCENTAGE",
            multiple="stack",
            height=6,
            aspect=2,
            kind='hist', 
            bins=BINNING_VALUE, 
            stat='density',
            ax=0,
            kde=True).set(title='Percentage of unsatisfied basic needs histogram')

ax.set(xlabel='%UBN', ylabel='Relative quantity of districts')


plt.axvline(x=districts.UBN_PERCENTAGE.mean(),
            color='red')
plt.axvline(x=districts.UBN_PERCENTAGE.median(),
            color='green')
plt.axvline(x=mode(districts.UBN_PERCENTAGE,BINNING_VALUE),
            color='blue')

plt.legend(handles=tags)
```

My result is this one:

[image]
Where 'Densidad Habitacional' means 'Population Density', and 'Necesidades Básicas Insatisfechas (NBI)' means 'Unsatisfied Basic Needs (UBN)'.

So then, in the first histogram plot shown at the screenshot, the first bar (at the left of all), starts at range 0. However, in the second one, we can see that the first bar doesn't start at 0, but in a greater value instead.

Also, viewing these values, I can also see that there's something wrong: in the second interval we have 60 observations, and in the third one, we have 30. However, at the histogram, we can see that the third bar has a lower height than the half or the second one, since 30 is exactly the half of 60.

I have defined a function which returns me a sequence with the frequency of every interval, and also a sequence with those delimiters, like this:

frequencies: [5.0, 60.0, 30.0, 17.0, 10.0, 11.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0]

delimiters: [0.0, 2.29, 4.57, 6.86, 9.15, 11.44, 13.72, 16.01, 18.3, 20.59, 22.87, 25.16]

Those are the corresponding values to the second histogram shown (UBN Percentage).

I've also used these values returned by that function, to calculate the mode of the variable in another defined function.

My code of these functions is this one:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
"""
In the constant 'BINNING_VALUE", we define the quantity of intervals in which we will subdivide 
the statistical population (we refer here to the number of records, not to the number of habitants),
to carry out the corresponding analysis.
it just so happens that conveniently, we have a total of 141 records in our database, being such number
a perfect square of 12, so that this value it turns out to us ideal to carry out that binning.
#of intervals will correspond to this value less 1. That's it, if we have 12 delimiters, then we'll have 11 intervals.
As an important issue, this value determines the quantity of interval delimitations, whereby the quantity
""";

BINNING_VALUE=12


"""    
This function recives as a parameter in 'column', a column of N observations, (which can be a Pandas Series),
and in 'bins, the quantity of delimitations of class intervals, in which we categorize those observations.
It returns both a list with the class intervals, with their corresponding frequency in each of its elements,
and a list of divisions, which defines the range of each interval.

For example, if recieve have a column of 16 rows, like this:
Index    Value
0         15
1         9
2         2
3         5
4         27
5         1
6         7
7         18
8         25
9         1
10        42
11        48
12        37
13        31
14        45
15        33

And then, our bin value is 4, it will return the following sequences:
interval_list: [7,4,5]
ranges_list: [0,16,32,48]
""";

def intervals(column,bins):

    #In 'max_value', I'll store the maximum value of the element in the recived column.
    max_value=column.max()

    #I generate a ranges list (converted from an array with 'tolist' function),
    #with a length equal to the bins parameter (quantity of class intervals + 1),
    #whose values will go from 0 to the maximum value of the column element, linearly subdivided.
    ranges_list=np.linspace(0,max_value,bins).tolist()

    #I generate an array with a length equal to the quantity of class intervals (bins -1),
    #initially loaded with zeros.
    intervals_array=np.zeros(bins-1)

    #With a for loop (in which I need the indexes value, starting at position 1), I iterate over
    #the ranges list with the 'i' variable, so I can also iterate over the class interval
    for i in range(1,bins):

        #I declare a variable, which will be reseted to 0 in each iteration of
        #the outer loop, in which I'll count the column items located into each range
        count_range_elements=0

        #With a nested for, I'll iterate over each element of the column
        for element in column:
            #If the column element value where I'm standing now, lies within the class interval
            #which I'm standing in the outer loop
            if element > ranges_list[i-1] and element <= ranges_list[i]:
                #I increase the element counter
                count_range_elements+=1

        #Once executed the inner for, I load in position i-1 of my class intervals array,
        #the quantity of elements I've counted in the corresponding range
        intervals_array[i-1]=count_range_elements

    #Once executed both nested for loops, I have now my class intervals array loaded
    #with the corresponding values

    #I convert my class intervals array into a list
    intervals_list=intervals_array.tolist()

    #I return a tuple with both the class intervals list and the ranges list
    return (intervals_list, ranges_list)


    
"""
This function recives as a parameter in 'column', a column of N observations, and in 'bins, the quantity of delimitations of class intervals, in which we categorize those observations.
It returns the approximate mode, calculated for such column, according to quantity of class intervlas quantity ('bins' value - 1 ), into we'll bin our data
""";
def mode(column,bins):

    #From the 'intervals' function, to which I pass the recived parameters 'column' and 'bins',
    #I'm getting the sequences with the needed values to calculate the mode
    intervals_list, ranges_list = intervals(column,bins)

    #From the intervals list, I'm storing the index to its maximum value.
    #This will be the position of our modal class interval (where the mode is found)
    ind_max_val = intervals_list.index(max(intervals_list))

    #The lower limit of the modal class interval, will be the element of the ranges
    #list, whose index is equal to the one correspondent to the maximum element of the
    #class intervals list
    lower_limit=ranges_list[ind_max_val]

    #Values 'a' and 'b' represents:
    #a: Difference between the height of the modal interval, and previous interval
    #b: Difference between the height of the modal interval, and next interval
    #Since these values are calculated based on the position of modal interval, depending if
    #this one is located at and extreme of the list, or in the middle of it, we need this values
    #outside of the scope of the 'if/else' sentences, so we declarate this variables here, with
    #0 as it's initial value.
    a=0
    b=0

    #In the 'c' value, we'll have the amplitude of class modal interval
    #(as like any other, since the amplitude is the same for all intervals)
    c=ranges_list[ind_max_val+1] - ranges_list[ind_max_val]

    #We calculate the 'a' value, depending if the modal interval is at the
    #start of the list (at the left of all), or if it doesn't
    if ind_max_val > 0:
        a=intervals_list[ind_max_val] - intervals_list[ind_max_val-1]
    else:
        a=intervals_list[ind_max_val]

    #We calculate the 'b' value, depending if the modal interval is at the
    #end of the list (at the right of all), or if it doesn't
    if ind_max_val < (bins-1):
        b=intervals_list[ind_max_val] - intervals_list[ind_max_val+1]
    else:
        b=intervals_list[ind_max_val]     

    #Once obtained every value needed, we'll apply it in the mode formula,
    #and we store the result in a variable
    mode= lower_limit + (a/(a+b))*c

    #Finally, we return the calculated mode value
    return mode
```

Since I'm not a native english speaker, if someone finds a grammar mistake somewhere, please correct me.

Does anyone have an idea of what should I do?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Posts are easier to answer if they'd include reproducible code and data, and concentrate on one concrete question. The starting value of a histogram is usually the lowest of the data points, which often is different from zero. Also note that your code is quite confusing, as `sns.displot` is a figure-level function, and doesn't return an `ax`.  The delimiters aren't shown by default, as they usually have too many digits to be displayed adequately. Maybe you could try `sns.histplot` and provide your own bins?

Answer (score -1):

I've resolved this issues by setting the 'bins' attribute with the list of class intervals returned by my 'intervals' function, instead of the number of bins, like this:

```
#We assign diffent colours for the mean, the median, and the mode (red, green, and blue), for the legend of the graphics plotted
ref_mean = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='Mean')
ref_median = mpatches.Patch(color='green', label='Median')
ref_mode = mpatches.Patch(color='blue', label='Mode')
tags=[ref_mean,ref_median,ref_mode]

...

ax = sns.displot(data=districts,
        x="POPULATION_DENSITY",
        multiple="stack",
        height=6,
        aspect=2,
        kind='hist', 
        bins=intervals(districts.POPULATION_DENSITY,BINNING_VALUE)[1], #Instead of bins=BINNING_VALUE, 
        stat='density',
        kde=True).set(title='Density Population Histogram')

ax.set(xlabel='Density Population (hab/km´2)', ylabel='Relative quantity of districts')

plt.axvline(x=districts.POPULATION_DENSITY.mean(),
        color='red')
plt.axvline(x=districts.POPULATION_DENSITY.median(),
        color='green')
plt.axvline(x=mode(x=districts.POPULATION_DENSITY,BINNING_VALUE),
        color='blue')

plt.legend(handles=tags)

ax = sns.displot(data=districts,
        x="UBN_PERCENTAGE",
        multiple="stack",
        height=6,
        aspect=2,
        kind='hist', 
        bins=intervals(districts.UBN_PERCENTAGE,BINNING_VALUE)[1], #Instead of bins=BINNING_VALUE, 
        stat='density',
        ax=0,
        kde=True).set(title='Percentage of unsatisfied basic needs histogram')

ax.set(xlabel='%UBN', ylabel='Relative quantity of districts')


plt.axvline(x=districts.UBN_PERCENTAGE.mean(),
        color='red')
plt.axvline(x=districts.UBN_PERCENTAGE.median(),
        color='green')
plt.axvline(x=mode(districts.UBN_PERCENTAGE,BINNING_VALUE),
        color='blue')

plt.legend(handles=tags)
```

So then, my result is this one:
[image]

Now, we can see that the calculated mode value by the function, concides exactly with the graphic method used to find it.

As a detail, here's the value of each measure:

Mean: 6.468369

Median: 5.000000

Mode: 3.767273